# Create XElement from invalid or partial XML String

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am working with a vendor supplied application that stores XML data as byte array in a SQL database table. I have found if the XML data is "too long" (meaning by a possible predetermined length in black box code provided by the vendor) the XML is truncated and a second record, containing the remainder of the XML data, is created.

My task is to take these "linked" records and merge them into one valid XML string. These linked records can be broken off anywhere, in the middle of an element, node, etc. There is no rhyme or reason to where the XML string is broken.

Taking the invalid XML data and loading it into an XElement causes an error "Tag  has no closing tag".

I've also tried using an XmlReader and reading through each Node, based on [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b44cd6e-a214-4929-a666-32705cce7aa2/xml-fragment-and-linq-to-xml?forum=xmlandnetfx)  as well as [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387035.aspx). They also result in the above missing tag error.

Is there a way to take these partial xml strings and merge them? Or am I simply stuck?

The vendor application we use does perform this merge, but that code is hidden from me.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the byte arrays or strings *before* converting them to XML?

Comment: Try html parsers(like HtmlAgilityPack) which are less sensitive to invalid input.

Comment: Both "fragments" as I call them have exactly the same declarations, and root elements.  So throwing the Bute arrays together won't work for me unless I iterate over the second array throwing out what I don't need

Comment: Thank you Ever. I will give that a try

Comment: @Eser, that worked perfectly. Would you mind adding that as a response so I may accept it as an answer?

Comment: @plstoner It is "too poor" to be an answer that is why I posted as a comment. You can prepare a good answer to your own question and accept it.